# Forma Correta de Escrever "Eu Lírico/Poético"

Tags: ortografia, gramática, pontuação

Gostaria apenas de tomar conhecimento no que toca ao modo de como se elabora a escrita da expressão acima referida. Após a receção da correção do meu exame de Português, vim a perceber que, no mínimo, 5 pontos me foram retirados, pois, ao que parece (e por surpresa minha) a forma de abordar o *eu* lírico estava incorreta, da minha parte.
Tipicamente, estruturo uma frase genérica como a seguir está apresentada:

- Aos olhos do eu lírico, aquele espaço era radiante.

Um ponto foi-me descontado, cada vez que escrevia "eu lírico" - a minha questão é: Porquê? Sei que a escrita em itálico (ou sublinhar sob a palavra "eu") ou a inserção da mesma entre aspas estão corretas, mas sempre pensei que apenas 'eu lírico' (sem aspas) também fosse aceitável.
Deverei pedir que me revejam o exame? Ou será o desconto legítimo e não há quaisquer chances de me recuperarem estes pontos?

Comment: Handy, bem-vindo à comunidade. Retirei as saudações e agradecimentos da tua pergunta, porque aqui neste site a pergunta deve ser simplesmente a pergunta e mais nada. Podes perguntar o que quiseres sem agradecer :)

Comment: Handy, falei hoje com duas professoras de português. Elas ensinam num nível inferior, mas disseram-me imediatamente que o termo usado atualmente é *eu poético*. Não ligaram nada à questão do hífen ou aspas. Estranharam a penalização "multiplicada". A respeito da tua outra pergunta, elas dizem que esse uso dos três pontos é incorreto (mas eu já vi isso ser usado). Também me indicaram o IAVE, ondes encontras as provas e critérios de classificação. Tens [aqui](http://www.iave.pt/images/arquivo_de_provas/2019/EFN_639_Port/EX-Port639-F1-2019-CC-VD_net.pdf) a do teu exame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002) escreve exatamente como tu escreveste:

> **eu** […] **eu lírico** LIT no poema, voz que expressa a subjetividade do poeta e/ou a maneira pela qual o mundo exterior se converte em vivência interior

Fui ao [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.pt/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0,5&q=%22eu%20l%C3%ADrico%22&scisbd=1), para ver como escrevem os académicos da área, e o uso divide-se entre *eu lírico* e *eu-lírico* (este itálico não é deles; é meu, para indicar que que me refiro ao termo e não ao seu significado, como em “eu uso pouco a palavra *eu*”).

A justificação possível no [Acordo Ortográfico de 1990](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1990) (Base XV, ponto 1) ou no [Formulário Ortográfico de 1943 (Brasil)](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1943) (Base XIV, pontos 45, 46) para o hífen de *eu-lírico* é pensar-se que os dois elementos “não conservam, considerados isoladamente, a sua significação, mas o conjunto constitui uma unidade semântica” (FO 1943), como *ano-luz* ou *arco-íris*.

A minha primeira reação foi que *eu* e *lírico* em *eu lírico* conservam cada um as suas significações, o que dispensaria o hífen (mas eu sinto o mesmo em relação a *guarda-noturno*, e é mesmo com hífen). Pelos vistos os académicos estão divididos neste ponto.

Itálicos e sublinhados não encontrei, e entre aspas encontrei só em dois livros no Google Books.

Itálicos e sublinhados podem servir para realçar, mas a decisão de realçar ou não, não é abrangida pelas normas ortográficas. Os outros usos do itálico e sublinhado, como indicar títulos de obras, não se aplicam ao nosso caso.

Pode-se usar aspas para indicar uma significação fora do habitual, o que poderia justificar *“eu lírico”* ou *“eu” lírico*. Mas o Houaiss já regista o substantivo *eu* com os significados “**2** a individualidade da pessoa humana **3** *por extensão* forma assumida por uma personalidade num dado momento <*o meu eu de outrora não existe mais*>”. O *eu* do *eu lírico* é também uma extensão disto, de modo que aspas me parecem uma preciosidade aqui, e, como já observei, raramente se encontram na literatura.

**Conclusão**: em geral, *eu lírico* está correto, haja vista do Houaiss e uso na literatura; no teu caso particular, a tua escola ou quem quer que seja que define os programas e é responsável pelos exames poderá ter as suas ideias, mas para considerar *eu lírico* errado (a única alternativa razoável parece-me *eu-lírico*) isso deveria estar definido no material de estudo.

Não te posso dizer se deves ou não solicitar a revisão do exame. Também não sei se um pedido de revisão pode ir acompanhado da tua fundamentação; se pode, espero ter-te fornecido munição útil.

Comment: Desde já, devo agradecer-te pela pesquisa aprimorada no que toca a este assunto. Quanto ao pedido de revisão, terei de dedicar mais algum tempo para concluir se o deverei efetuar - de qualquer modo, acrescento apenas que é penoso que um desconto tão marcante me tenha sido feito, apesar de o modo de como eu recorri à expressão não estar incorreto (ao que parece).

Comment: Para adicionar mais uma informação: para cada vez que escrevi "eu lírico", duas linhas a sublinhado, uma atrás e outra à frente da palavra _eu_, foram inseridas pelo professor, o que me leva a crer que o mesmo acredite que _"eu" lírico_ é a forma correta de abordar a expressão (e não necessariamente _eu-lírico_ - apesar de, provavelmente, também a aceitar, admitidamente).